# Find entry which has same has many along with its details

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help on wring a query which would pull an entry which has same has many. A teacher can opt for any subjects to teach , a student can opt for any subjects to be taught. Need to find a teacher who has opted to teach for same combination of subjects that a student has opted for.

Table Student

```
id name
1  x
2  y
```

Table student_Subjects

```
id subject_id student_id
1  1          1
2  2          1
3  1          2
```

Teacher

```
id name
1  tx
2  ty
```

Table teacher_subjects

```
id subject_id teacher_id
1  1          2
2  2          2
3  1          1
```

Subject

```
id name
1  English
2  Maths
```

Now need to find a teacher who has opted to teach same subjects as student x along with names of both student and teacher.

I had asked similar question which got me result without student name and teacher name.
here is the query for that:

```
 SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(subject_id ORDER BY subject_id) as teacher_concat ,teacher_id
       FROM teacher_subjects 
       GROUP BY teacher_id 
       HAVING teacher_concat IN
                    (SELECT group_concat(subject_id ORDER BY subject_id)
                     FROM student_subjects GROUP BY student_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
select
        teacher.id, 
        teacher.name,
        student.id,
        student.name
from
        teacher,
        student,
        (select
                teacher_id,
                GROUP_CONCAT(
                        distinct subject_id
                        order by subject_id
                        separator ' '
                ) x
        from
                teacher_subjects
        group by
                teacher_id
        ) t,
        (select
                student_id
                GROUP_CONCAT(
                        distinct subject_id
                        order by subject_id
                        separator ' '
                ) x
        from
                student_subjects
        group by
                student_id
        ) s
where
        t.x=s.x and
        t.teacher_id=teacher.teacher_id and
        s.student_id=student.student_id
```

Comment: Gives an error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group by subject_id
                ) m
        from
                teacher_sub' at line 13 @Lajos

Comment: Thanks. I fixed 2 things, I hope it helps.